# APC cache making apache consume all CPU usage

Tags: apache, apc

Greetings,

I'm trying to install APC in order to deal with a high Apache RAM usage.

I've followed this [instructions here](http://linuxhostingsupport.net/blog/how-to-install-and-configure-apc-cache-on-a-centos-server) and, from the moment I've edited php.ini my Apache CPU usage EXPLODED.

What did I do wrong? How can I be sure APC is working fine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. In the shell run php -i | grep apc to see if APC is enable
2. Install apc.php (cd /; find -name apc.php | grep apc) somewhere on web doc root to monitor Your APC installation